# How to make REST Request to Baasbox server using POSTMAN extension?

Tags: json, rest, request, mbaas

I just installed Baasbox on my laptop and everything are work well. But when I try to make a request to create a new user, or anothe REST request using POSTMAN extension, I always got "Invalid Json" error. Is there any mistakes with my request?
[image: error attachment]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that you want to create a user.

In this case you have to set parameters like in the image below.

In particular you have to set "raw" instead of form-data, and also you do not need to set the Authorization header when signing up.

Further info here: [BaasBox Signup API](http://www.baasbox.com/documentation/?shell#sign-up)
[image: Postman extension screenshot]